# Stock level not updating in Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, import, stock, out-of-stock

I use data link by holbi, when I go onto Magento it is showing the correct amount of stock but my website is still showing zero, I have to click on the product in Magento then save and it will update.

Does anyone know a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes , try to check if it occurs with other products as well.

1. try to re-index and clear the cache.
2. Also check compared to simple and bundled products.
3. See in which store view is applying on the left side .

Answer (score 1):

Reindex the stock status index after importing. If you want to automate this, you can do it with this shell command:

```
php /path/to/magento/shell/indexer.php --reindex cataloginventory_stock
```